# Non-Hermitian, non-unitary square matrix factorized into unitary and Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Is it (always) possible to write a non-Hermitian, non-unitary square matrix as a product of A and B such that A is unitary (but may or may not be Hermitian) and B is Hermitian (but may or may not be non-unitary)? If not under what conditions it is possible?

Comment: Yes and in fact, the Hermitian matrix can be chosen to be positive semidefinite, by [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is always possible, analogous to writing every *real* (square) matrix as a product of orthogonal and symmetric matrices.

For invertible square matrices, these results are cases of Iwasawa decompositions, which hold quite generally for semi-simple and reductive real Lie groups (and also for semi-simple and $p$-adic groups!) The case of non-invertible matrices probably follows by taking a limit, but I'm not absolutely certain... The proofs for the concrete cases are not soooo hard, but not trivial. The abstracted, intrinsic case has much more baggage.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is very helpful to know.

I am working on a physics problem that involves a lossy non-reciprocal system. I am proposing to describe a lossy, nonreciprocal system as a combination of a lossless nonreciprocal system and a lossy reciprocal system. This effectively means writing a non-Hermitian, non-unitary square matrix as a product of A and B such that A is unitary but non-Hermitian and B is Hermitian but non-unitary.

Is there a related theorem I could refer to? I don't have much background in Linear Algebra.